# Limitations of Deep Learning on Windows?

Tags: linux, windows

What are the disadvantages, if any, of running Deep Learning programs under Windows as opposed to Linux?

I’m assembling a new machine at home to experiment with Deep Learning, probably with Theano, designed around an Asus GTX 980 Ti Strix GPU card, and a Skylake i7 6700 CPU on an Asus motherboard. The Asus 980 Ti card has better cooling and is faster than the Nvidia 980 Ti reference card. The Asus GPU and motherboard come with Windows based software that monitors temperatures, controls fans speeds, controls CPU clock, etc., so it would appear I’m stuck with Windows.

Will Windows slow down Deep Learning training relative to Linux? Why or why not?

All suggestions are appreciated. Or please let me know if there is a way to control the Asus boards with Linux (Kubuntu.)

Thanks 
Laplace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some packages just don't support windows.

E.g. [CAFFE](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/installation.html) (There is an unofficial port - but it means that you can't count on it to be kept updated or supported)

If you are stuck with windows, did you think of running linux on a virtual machine?

Comment: Thanks. I haven't looked into linux on a virtual machine. Would that slow down the Deep Learning program, or is it fairly independent of the virtual machine once it starts executing?

Comment: I didn't try it, so I am speculating. I would expect the VM to be slower in case you've had CPU intensive calculations, because it is sharing resources with the main windows OS. But since the GPU will not be used by windows, it might not be slower.